# Not getting current data from database in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0, netbeans-8

We have a need to view all of the data, from a database table in a JTable model.

When I insert some fields into the database using EntityManager, and they appear to have been added to the database.

But, when I view the database in the view page it still shows the old data, and not new data from database.

I've tried EntityManager.clear(), and EntityManager.flush() but they don't seem to have worked.

```
void setSavedCustomer() {
    EntityManager em = null;
    DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel) save_table.getModel();    
    try {
        em = JPAUtils.buildEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.flush();
        em.clear();           
        TypedQuery<TempSavedCustomerList> query = em.createQuery("select i from TempSavedCustomerList i JOIN FETCH i.customerIdFk ORDER BY i.id DESC", TempSavedCustomerList.class);     
        List<TempSavedCustomerList> customers = query.getResultList();
        model1.getDataVector().removeAllElements();  
        for (TempSavedCustomerList customer : customers) {
            model1.addRow(new Object[]{false, customer.getSaveDate(), customer.getCustomerIdFk().getFname() + " " + customer.getCustomerIdFk().getLname(), customer.getCustomerMobile(), customer.getTotalAmount(), customer, false});
        }           
       em.getTransaction().commit();            
    }
```

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: May be you forgot the flush/commit part but without code hard to tell.

Comment: Improved grammer.

Comment: after persist data on database when I click button it calls setSavedCustomer() to view saved customer list, but it shows me old data instead of new data from database here is the code of setSavedCustomer()